# Upload script - Javascript variable inside jQuery parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I can't tell if I'm misunderstanding the syntax or if I'm not understanding the concept.  I want to take a javascript variable and concatenate it into a URL parameter inside a jQuery function.  The variable is reassigned by another upload script's jQuery function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var trackid = 12;


jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

    $('#mainftp2').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : 'js/uploadifymultiple/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : 'js/uploadifymultiple/uploadify.php?<?php echo urlencode("songid=" . $songid . "&userid=" . $userid . "&trackid=);?>'+trackid+'"',
    'multi'         : true,
    'auto'          : true,
    'height'        :   '32', //height of your browse button file
    'width'         :   '250', //width of your browse button file
    'sizeLimit' :   '51200000',  //remove this to set no limit on upload size
    'simUploadLimit' : '3', //remove this to set no limit on simultaneous uploads
    'buttonImg' : 'img/browse.png',
    'cancelImg' : 'img/cancel.png',
        'folder'    : '<?php echo $multiFolder?>', //folder to save uploads to
        onProgress: function() {
          $('#loader2').show();
        },
        onComplete: function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
          $('#loader2').hide();
          $('#allfiles2').load(location.href+" #allfiles2>*","");
          $('#filesUploaded2').attr('value', ''+response+'');

          //location.reload(); //uncomment this line if youw ant to refresh the whole page instead of just the #allfiles div
        }   
    });

    $('ul li:odd').addClass('odd');

}); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the location of your double-quotes, you're missing one inside the PHP fragment, and have an extra one at the end of the URL.

```
script: 'js/uploadifymultiple/uploadify.php?<?php echo urlencode("songid=" . $songid . "&userid=" . $userid . "&trackid=);?>'+trackid+'"',
```

First we'll focus on the part we know is wrong:

```
'uploadify.php?<?php echo urlencode("songid=" . $songid . "&userid=" . $userid . "&trackid=);?>'+trackid+'"',
```

The question mark is after the `.php` part. `songid` and `userid` seem fine.

```
'uploadify.php?<?php echo urlencode("&trackid=);?>'+trackid+'"',
```

Oh crap, where's the closing quote in our call to `urlencode`?

```
'uploadify.php?<?php echo urlencode("&trackid=");?>'+trackid+'"',
```

So now we have a string that's part JavaScript, part PHP, and it's right.

```
'uploadify.php?etc&trackid=' + trackid + '"',
```

But URLs don't have trailing quotes, so there must be an extra.

```
'uploadify.php?etc&trackid=' + trackid,
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time debugging this.  Any chance you could write out what you mean?